# rvm environment load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rvm, zsh

what I need to write to my environment to repair my rvm?
(and when I had put `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` into a top of `.zshenv` file and the `.zshrc` file nothing happen)

```
-> % rails
zsh: correct 'rails' to 'tail' [nyae]? %
sky7@hi7sky [03:09:14] [~] 
-> % rvm reload
RVM reloaded!
sky7@hi7sky [03:09:17] [~] 
-> % rails --version
Rails 3.2.1
```

How I can fix it? thx

And more info:

```
$ diff before_reload_env after_reload_env 
15c15
< PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:/home/sky7/.rvm/bin
---
> PATH=/home/sky7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@edge/bin:/home/sky7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/bin:/home/sky7/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin:/home/sky7/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:/home/sky7/.rvm/bin
82a83,85
> rvm_ruby_string=ruby-1.9.3-head
> rvm_env_string=ruby-1.9.3-head@edge
> __rvm_env_loaded=-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix your initialization files use:

```
rvm get head --auto
```

then make sure you read:

- [shell login description](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/support/faq/#shell_login)
- [fixing login in gnome](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/gnome-terminal/)
- [fixing login in screen](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/workflow/screen/)

Comment: -> % rvm get latest
/base:source:3: no such file or directory: /base
/version:source:4: no such file or directory: /version

Original installed RVM version:                                                                                                               

rvm 1.10.2 by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

You already have the latest version!
RVM reloaded!

But its didn't help me

Comment: when fighting issues use only `head` or `stable` RVM, `latest` is no more supported in bug reports

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reloading your shell? `source ~/.zshrc`. If that doesn't work try opening a new terminal tab or window and see if your rvm environment is loaded now.